# Javascript in browser - make HTTPS request with custom x509 certificate?

Tags: javascript, x509

I am making a progressive web app which operates in a somewhat decentralized fashion. In practice, this means that the app is going to be making requests (https definitely, maybe websockets as well) to foreign servers, and I need to ensure that the server can be validated using a custom root certificate (NOT whatever is in the browser's trust store).

What's the easiest way to do this? Do I need to use an implementation of these protocols in JavaScript like [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge), or is there a better way?

Comment: How are you going to get your certificate to the app without trusting the built in certificates?

Comment: @CharlesBamford Obtaining and uploading a root certificate is the responsibility of the user.

Comment: I say 'uploading' loosely, what I really mean is it gets stored in localstorage or similar.